# How do I transform two objects to the same frame of reference

Tags: objects, transforms, displacement, dimensions

I have two objects, a cube and a second object which I created from a bezier curve.
They are sitting above a plane.
[image]

For the object on the left

[image]

The Y Dimension is dictating its width (left to right measurement) as seen from this perspective.

[image]

For the object on the Right (created from a curve),
the Y Dimension is dictating its height (top to bottom measurement) as seen from this perspective.
I know the terms Width, Height and Length depend on a particular context. I know by rotating the object on the left I can try and make it match the object on the left so that its height equates to the Y dimension, but ....
Is there some way of reassigning or changing the designation of these things so that I am not always rotating objects.

[image]

Another extension of this is to consider the respective rotation of the objects.
The object on the left has a rotation shown above, but on the right, we have the rotation shown below.
Before I begin designing anything I would like to re-reference these objects so that in this view both their rotations are 0.

I hope this makes sense. I am very new to blender, so perhaps I am missing something obvious here.

[image]

Comment: try **CTRL+A** and *Apply all transforms*

Comment: Thank you @MarkusvonBroady. That was just what I needed! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Applying _all_ transforms throws the objects' origins back World 0. You have the option of applying rotation and scale separately, if that's better for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @MarkusvonBroady. I positioned both objects in the desired starting position. Then I selected both objects and pressed Ctrl + A, and then selected *Apply all transforms*. After that, the objects both had the same frame of reference, same angles of rotation etc.
We can also select individual transforms to apply, for example, we could just apply rotation.

[image]